# Reshape several groups of variables, following a previously reshaped index column

Tags: r, data.table, reshape, tidyr

I am trying to reshape a data.table from wide to long in R. I have several groups of variables that I need to reduce, but my initial approach to do it one group at a time is looking very error prone and I'd like an alternative. In this reproducible example I create two groups of variables (`XX` and `YYY`) in a similar manner as the original data.

My solution works in this example but the original data table has so many columns that I am uneasy in trusting this code. I am not sure if the problem is in my implementation or the approach itself - I would prefer to [keep it simple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) if possible.

**Q:** Is there a better way to solve this?

**Example data**

```
library(data.table)

dt.orig <- data.table(ID= 1:3,
                      a = c("Y", "Y", "N"),
                      b = c("N", "Y", "Y"),
                      XXa=c(101, 102, 103),
                      XXb=c(110, 120, 130),
                      YYYa=c(201, 202, 203),
                      YYYb=c(210, 220, 230))


dt.goal <- data.table(ID=c(1,1,2,2,3,3),
                      obs=c("a", "b"),
                      outcome = c("Y", "N", "Y", "Y", "N", "Y"),
                      XX=c(101, 110, 102, 120, 103, 130),
                      YYY=c(201, 210, 202, 220, 203, 230))

> dt.orig
   ID a b XXa XXb YYYa YYYb
1:  1 Y N 101 110  201  210
2:  2 Y Y 102 120  202  220
3:  3 N Y 103 130  203  230
> dt.goal
   ID obs outcome  XX YYY
1:  1   a       Y 101 201
2:  1   b       N 110 210
3:  2   a       Y 102 202
4:  2   b       Y 120 220
5:  3   a       N 103 203
6:  3   b       Y 130 230
```

`dt.orig` represents the original data and `dt.goal` is what I intend to achieve. My initial attempt following the `tidyr` package vignette is as follows:

**Attempt 1: `tidyr/dplyr` approach**

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

dt.orig[, .(ID, a, b)] %>%
  pivot_longer(
    cols = c("a", "b"),
    names_to = "obs",
    values_to = "outcome"
  ) %>% data.table -> dt.tidyr1

dt.orig[, .(ID, XXa, XXb, YYYa, YYYb)] %>%
  pivot_longer(
             cols = XXa:YYYb,
             names_to = c(".value", "obs"),
             names_pattern = "(XX|YYY)(.)",
              ) %>% data.table -> dt.tidyr2

dt.tidyr1[, .(ID, obs, outcome)] == dt.goal[, .(ID, obs, outcome)] # test passes
dt.tidyr2[, .(ID, obs, XX, YYY)] == dt.goal[, .(ID, obs, XX, YYY)] # test passes

> merge(dt.tidyr1, dt.tidyr2)
   ID obs outcome  XX YYY
1:  1   a       Y 101 201
2:  1   b       N 110 210
3:  2   a       Y 102 202
4:  2   b       Y 120 220
5:  3   a       N 103 203
6:  3   b       Y 130 230
```

In the above code I first create a pair of name/value for `obs` and outcome from `a` and `b`. Since all variable groups include `a` and `b` in their naming scheme I can then use this fact to pass through all groups with a single *regex*.

I can then merge or join the two data tables into the final.

**Attempt 2: the `data.table` way**

Following the same principle, I can start melting the original a and b into obs and outcome, then follow to a second step (not shown here for brevity) for each var group. In this case I succeeded melting one var group at a time, so in this example, first do all XX, then all YYY. Pros/Cons: pro is that I don't need to create several step tables to finish the process. Con: there's not enough coffee in the world to finish this approach with all var groups in the actual data (and trust the results).

```
dt.melt1 <- melt(dt.orig,
                 id.vars = c("ID", "XXa", "XXb", "YYYa", "YYYb"),
                 measure = c("a", "b"),
                 variable.name = "obs",
                 value.name = "outcome")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the dplyr version is fine. You could just make the regex in the pivot_longer more generalisable to scale up the number of columns. Also you could flatten out the columns a and b to a list so you don't have to deal with making a second dataframe and merging.

```
# flatten cols a,b 
outcome <-  c(t(select(dt.orig, c(a, b))))

# pivot longer on regex and add outcome list
dt.orig %>%  
  pivot_longer(-c(ID, a, b), 
               names_to = c(".value", "obs"),
               names_pattern = "(.*)(.)") %>% 
  mutate(outcome = outcome) %>% 
  select(-c(a, b))



     ID obs      XX   YYY outcome
1     1 a       101   201 Y      
2     1 b       110   210 N      
3     2 a       102   202 Y      
4     2 b       120   220 Y      
5     3 a       103   203 N      
6     3 b       130   230 Y
```

Comment: Thank you. You correctly guessed what I left out of the question: I wanted to avoid creating a second table to merge. Will the regex you provided match all other columns that I didn't include in this example?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think `data.table::melt` has a mechanism to automatically split you "XXa" in to "XX" and "a", so you probably don't have a choice but to proceed in multiple steps with `data.table`. But here are two alternative ways to get your result, with a quick benchmark against @LRRR's nice tidyverse solution.

Data and libraries:

```r
library(data.table)
library(tidyverse)
library(microbenchmark)

dt.orig = data.table(ID= 1:3,
                     a = c("Y", "Y", "N"),
                     b = c("N", "Y", "Y"),
                     XXa=c(101, 102, 103),
                     XXb=c(110, 120, 130),
                     YYYa=c(201, 202, 203),
                     YYYb=c(210, 220, 230))
```

First `data.table` solution (wrapped in a function for the benchmark):

```r
dt_1 <- function() {
  dt = melt(dt.orig, 
            id.vars=c("a", "b", "ID"), 
            measure.vars=patterns("XX|YYY"),
            variable.factor=FALSE)
  dt = melt(dt,
            id.vars=c("ID", "variable", "value"),
            value.name="outcome",
            variable.name="obs",
            variable.factor=FALSE)
  dt = dt[substr(variable, nchar(variable), nchar(variable)) == obs]
  dt[, variable := substr(variable, 1, nchar(variable)-1)]
  dcast(dt, ID + obs + outcome ~ variable)
}
```

Second `data.table` solution:

```r
dt_2 <- function() {
  # ID-obs-outcome
  dt1 = melt(dt.orig[, .(ID, a, b)], 
             id.vars="ID",
             value.name="outcome",
             variable.name="obs",
             variable.factor=FALSE)

  # ID-obs-XX-YYY 
  dt2 = melt(dt.orig[, !c("a", "b")], 
             id.vars="ID",
             variable.factor=FALSE)
  dt2[, obs := substr(variable, nchar(variable), nchar(variable))]
  dt2[, variable := substr(variable, 1, nchar(variable)-1)]
  dt2 = dcast(dt2, ID + obs ~ variable)

  # merge
  merge(dt1, dt2, by=c("ID", "obs"))
}
```

`tidyverse` solution posted as a working answer by LRRR:

```r
tidy_1 <- function(){
  # flatten cols a,b 
  outcome <-  c(t(select(dt.orig, c(a, b))))
  # pivot longer on regex and add outcome list
  dt.orig %>%  
    pivot_longer(-c(ID, a, b), 
                 names_to = c(".value", "obs"),
                 names_pattern = "(.*)(.)") %>% 
    mutate(outcome = outcome) %>% 
    select(-c(a, b))
}
```

Benchmark:

```r
microbenchmark(dt_1(), dt_2(), tidy_1(), times=20)
#> Unit: milliseconds
#>      expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq      max neval cld
#>    dt_1()  2.695407  2.716623  4.968294  2.900856  3.101634 43.51289    20  a 
#>    dt_2()  4.849555  5.027214  6.704733  5.160479  6.297621 18.93398    20  a 
#>  tidy_1() 13.149104 13.515273 16.439809 13.769746 15.506042 47.13444    20   b
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that in two lines:

```
dt.res <- melt(dt.orig, "ID", patterns("^[ab]$", "^XX", "^YYY"), "obs", c("outcome", "XX", "YYY"))
setorder(dt.res, ID)[, obs := unname(c("1" = "a", "2" = "b")[obs])]
```

Output

```
> dt.res[]
   ID obs outcome  XX YYY
1:  1   a       Y 101 201
2:  1   b       N 110 210
3:  2   a       Y 102 202
4:  2   b       Y 120 220
5:  3   a       N 103 203
6:  3   b       Y 130 230
```

Here is a slightly lengthier version of the same code above

```
dt.res <- 
  melt(
    dt.new2, 
    id.vars = "ID", measure.vars = patterns("^[ab]$", "^XX", "^YYY"), 
    variable.name = "obs", value.name = c("outcome", "XX", "YYY")
  )
setorder(dt.res, ID)[, obs := unname(c("1" = "a", "2" = "b")[obs])]
```

**Additional Explanations**

It seems that except for the `ID` column, you have three groups of columns that need to be simultaneously pivoted: those without any prefix (i.e. `a` and `b`), those with prefix `XX` and those with prefix `YYY`. If **within each group the column with suffix `a` always appears before the one with suffix `b`**, you can then `melt` those groups of columns simultaneously, as `data.table v1.9.6` and after natively supports such operation. You need to specify each column group using `regex`.

That's why we have `patterns("^[ab]$", "^XX", "^YYY")`, which captures the three column groups we attempt to `melt`. After the `melt` operation, you will get a `data.table` like this:

```
   ID obs outcome  XX YYY
1:  1   1       Y 101 201
2:  2   1       Y 102 202
3:  3   1       N 103 203
4:  1   2       N 110 210
5:  2   2       Y 120 220
6:  3   2       Y 130 230
```

Instead of `a` and `b`, we get `1` and `2` in `obs` because the `melt` operation automatically sets the first match within each group as `"1"`, second as `"2"`, and so on. Later we can do a reset of this column by specifying  `"1" = "a"` and `"2" = "b"`. However, as you may be aware, if the column with suffix `a` appears after the one with `b`, then we can't use this mapping `c("1" = "a", "2" = "b")` anymore. This is why we have to ensure that each column group is properly ordered.

For a better illustration of this ordering issue, see the code below:

```
# Assume that your data.table looks like this
> dt.unordered
   ID b a XXa YYYb XXb YYYa
1:  1 N Y 101  210 110  201
2:  2 Y Y 102  220 120  202
3:  3 Y N 103  230 130  203

# See the difference now?
> dt.wrong <- melt(dt.unordered, "ID", patterns("^[ab]$", "^XX", "^YYY"), "obs", c("outcome", "XX", "YYY"))
> dt.wrong[]
   ID obs outcome  XX YYY
1:  1   1       N 101 210
2:  2   1       Y 102 220
3:  3   1       Y 103 230
4:  1   2       Y 110 201
5:  2   2       Y 120 202
6:  3   2       N 130 203
```

So if you cannot ensure the order within each group, perhaps do a pre-processing to fix the column order. In this way, you can also get the correct results.

```
> setcolorder(dt.unordered, sort(names(dt.unordered)))
> dt.fixed <- melt(dt.unordered, "ID", patterns("^[ab]$", "^XX", "^YYY"), "obs", c("outcome", "XX", "YYY"))
> dt.fixed[]
   ID obs outcome  XX YYY
1:  1   1       Y 101 201
2:  2   1       Y 102 202
3:  3   1       N 103 203
4:  1   2       N 110 210
5:  2   2       Y 120 220
6:  3   2       Y 130 230
```

In summary, if you have all columns pre-ordered, do this:

```
dt.res <- melt(dt.orig, "ID", patterns("^[ab]$", "^XX", "^YYY"), "obs", c("outcome", "XX", "YYY"))
setorder(dt.res, ID)[, obs := unname(c("1" = "a", "2" = "b")[obs])]
```

if not, do this:

```
setcolorder(dt.orig, sort(names(dt.orig)))
dt.res <- melt(dt.orig, "ID", patterns("^[ab]$", "^XX", "^YYY"), "obs", c("outcome", "XX", "YYY"))
setorder(dt.res, ID)[, obs := unname(c("1" = "a", "2" = "b")[obs])]
```